# Is there any way to print the actual query that mysqli->execute() makes?

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a complex query that gets executed like this:

```
if ($stmt = $dbi->prepare($pt_query)) {   
        $stmt->bind_param('ssssssssi', $snome,$scognome,$ssocieta,$svia,$slocalita,$sprovincia,$scap,$stelefono,$sfax,$uid);
        $stmt->execute();           
        echo $dbi->error;
        $stmt->close();

    } else {
        printf("Error -> %s\n", $dbi->error);
    }
```

This thing is failing without any error, it simply doesn't update the database. Since there is a ton of data that gets treated before this thing I would like to know if there is any way to show the actual query that mysqli is executing in order to understand where the problem is.

Thank you.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be possible. Dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/962986/how-to-echo-a-mysqli-prepared-statement

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If your statement is failing, you should check `$stmt->error` (as opposed to `$dbi->error`). As far as getting the actual text of the query: it's not possible. When using prepared statements, the library is using a special protocol that doesn't generate an actual query string for each `->execute()` call.

Comment: Thank you, never knew about this. $stmt->error got me in the right direction.

Answer (score 5):

You could turn on logging on the MySQL DB itself, ie. add a log=*logfile* line to my.ini.

Refer to the [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/) for more information if needed.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a tool I found that may help [MySQLi Prepare Statement checker](http://www.mustbebuilt.co.uk/apps/mysql-prepare-checker/)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [PHP mysql website](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) there is no actual way of doing it. But you may try [this function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) as it gives you errors in your query.