# PHP/Mysql - How can I diplay what is inside query string?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a problem with my query. When I `var_dump` my query it says `bool(false)`.

How can I display the full query text?

PHP:

```
public function query($string, array $params = array()) {
        $this->count++;
        return mysql_query_params($string, $params);
}
public function updateArticle($article) {
        $rv = $this->db->query("UPDATE ats_Articles SET " .
            "art_CategoryID=$2, art_Title='$3', art_ShortText='$4', art_LongText='$5', art_Ln2BR=$6, art_Language='$7', " . 
            "art_DisplayCountry='$8', art_DateIn=$9, art_DateOut=$10, art_LinkedArt='$11', art_Download='$12', art_Icon='$13', " . 
            "art_IconLarge='$14', art_IconDesc='$15', art_Priority=$16, art_Location='$17', art_Keywords='$18', art_Desc='$19' " .
            "WHERE art_ID=$1;",
            array($article->art_ID, $article->art_CategoryID, $article->art_Title, $article->art_ShortText,
                  $article->art_LongText, $article->art_Ln2BR, $article->art_Language, $article->art_DisplayCountry,
                  $article->art_DateIn, $article->art_DateOut, $article->art_LinkedArt, $article-> art_Download,
                  $article->art_Icon, $article->art_IconLarge, $article->art_IconDesc, $article->art_Priority, $article->art_Location, $article->art_Keywords, $article->art_Desc));
        if ($rv === false ) {
            var_dump($rv); // bool(false)
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you show the method `db->query`?

Comment: On a sidenote you should use mysqli.

Comment: Are you used codeigniter??

Comment: First try to fire this query in phpmyadmin, and it will tell you error, if you have any in your query.

Comment: he wants to display the values in the query, as they came from an array in query params ...

Comment: @S.Pols Yeah sure wait a sec please.

Comment: Check the answer to this one (possible duplicate): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2691707/is-there-any-way-to-print-the-actual-query-that-mysqli-execute-makes

Comment: @S.Pols public function query

Comment: @hardiksolanki No, I work without framework.

Comment: @user3105439, you should edit your answer to show the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using codeigniter then `$this->db->last_query();` can help you definitely.

Comment: In that case you have to change the code of db class to debug sql statement.

Comment: Since you are using here mysql_query_params function. If this function contain mysql_query function then echo the sql query before execute.

Comment: Thanks. You mean something like this: echo("$string<br />");
        print_r($params);
        exit();

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure that the implementation of this function `mysql_query_params` is as follows, i just added a forth parameter (optional) for debugging

```
 mysql_query_params( $query, $parameters=array(), $database=false, $debug = false )
```

in your query function just call the forth parameter

```
public function query($string, array $params = array()) {
    $this->count++;
    return mysql_query_params($string, $params, false, true); // the forth is true for debugging
}
```

when you set the forth parameter to `true` the function will return string containing the query.

this is your function modified

```
function mysql_query_params__callback( $at ) {
        global $mysql_query_params__parameters;
        return $mysql_query_params__parameters[ $at[1]-1 ];
}
function mysql_query_params( $query, $parameters=array(), $database=false, $debug = false ) {
        // Escape parameters as required & build parameters for callback function
        global $mysql_query_params__parameters;
        foreach( $parameters as $k=>$v )
                $parameters[$k] = ( is_int( $v ) ? $v : ( NULL===$v ? 'NULL' : "'".mysql_real_escape_string( $v )."'" ) );
        $mysql_query_params__parameters = $parameters;

        $query = preg_replace_callback( '/\$([0-9]+)/', 'mysql_query_params__callback', $query);

        if($debug){
            return $query;
        }
        // Call using mysql_query
        if( false===$database )
                return mysql_query( $query );
        else    return mysql_query( $query , $database);
}
```