# How to print last executed query with bind parameter mysqli functions?

Tags: php, mysqli, bindparam

I am using bind parameter mysqli function to execute the queries in php . But i want to print last executed query everytime.

```
public function __construct(){
   $this->dbcon = new mysqli('localhost', '*****', '*****', 'db1');
  }

public function get_oderlist($email){
    $emailid = $this->dbcon->real_escape_string($email);
    $stmt =$this->dbcon->prepare("SELECT order_id,email,phone FROM order_historynew where email=? GROUP BY order_id ORDER BY id DESC"); 
    $stmt->bind_param('s',$emailid);  
    $stmt->execute(); 
    $stmt -> bind_result($order_id,$email,$phone);
    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        $Oderlist[]=array('Order_id'=>$order_id,'Useremail'=>$email,'Phone'=>$phone);
    }     
    if($Oderlist){
        return $Oderlist;
    }else{
        return false; 
    }       
}
```

Comment: use `$sth->debugDumpParams();` check http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.debugdumpparams.php

Comment: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::debugDumpParams() in C:\xampp\htdocs\!2\index.php on line 12

Comment: Check the correct answer :-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2691707/is-there-any-way-to-print-the-actual-query-that-mysqli-execute-makes

Comment: this should help : - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/962986/how-to-echo-a-mysqli-prepared-statement