# I want to print PHP query with parameters

Tags: php, parameters, echo

I have the following code

```
$name = 'myname';
$mail = 'my@mail.it';
$qwt = "INSERT INTO `agenz` (`name`, `email`) VALUES (?,?)";
$result = $connessione->prepare($qwt);
$result->bind_param('ss', $name, $mail); 
$result->execute();
```

I want print the query

```
"INSERT INTO `agenz` (`name`, `email`) VALUES ('myname','my@mail.it')"
```

for creating a log.So how to do that?

thanx.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get the SQL of a PreparedStatement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2382532/how-can-i-get-the-sql-of-a-preparedstatement)

Comment: May be [this](http://www.dummies.com/programming/php/how-to-display-php-variable-values/) will be helpfull

Comment: ***If it's `mysqli` then you can't do it***. why? check below links:-[How can I get the SQL of a PreparedStatement?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2382561/4248328)AND [Is there any way to print the actual query that mysqli->execute() makes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2691707/is-there-any-way-to-print-the-actual-query-that-mysqli-execute-makes)AND[How to echo a MySQLi prepared statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/962986/how-to-echo-a-mysqli-prepared-statement)

Answer (score 2):

Try fullQuery like below:

```
$name = 'myname';
$mail = 'my@mail.it';
$qwt = "INSERT INTO `agenz` (`name`, `email`) VALUES (?,?)";
$result = $connessione->prepare($qwt);
$result->bind_param('ss', $name, $mail); 
$result->execute(); 

echo $result->fullQuery;
```

or

```
$result->debugQuery();
var_dump($result->debugBindedVariables());
```

if you want to get the error

```
var_dump($result->errno);
```

Comment: Tnx!
If i use echo $result->fullQuery; i have an error
Notice: Undefined property: mysqli_stmt::$fullQuery

Comment: $result->errorCode(); if you use this will get the statement error details

Comment: tnx
Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::errorCode()

I want print the exact query!

Comment: did you come out from this problem? @Sonia Ghizzoni

Comment: @lalithkumar  i think no. he didn't

Comment: Yes $connessione is correct! The code work fine!
I have the error on
echo $result->fullQuery;

Comment: welcome...you can accept the answer if solved your problem@Sonia Ghizzoni

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined method PDOStatement::debugQuery()

Answer (score 1):

I have solved!

```
  $qwt = "INSERT INTO `age` (`name`,`email`) VALUES (?,?)";
  $par = array($name, $mail);

  $result = $connessione->prepare($qwt);
  $result->bind_param('ss', $par[0], $par[1]); 
  $result->execute();

  echo "contenuto: " .SqlDebug($qwt, $par); 

  function SqlDebug($raw_sql, $params=array())
  {
  $keys = array();
  $values = $params;  
  foreach ($params as $key => $value)
  {
    // check if named parameters (':param') or anonymous parameters ('?') are    used
    if (is_string($key)) { $keys[] = '/:'.$key.'/'; }
    else                 { $keys[] = '/[?]/'; }
    // bring parameter into human-readable format
    if (is_string($value))    { $values[$key] = "'" . $value . "'"; }
    elseif (is_array($value)) { $values[$key] = implode(',', $value); }
    elseif (is_null($value))  { $values[$key] = 'NULL'; }
  }
  $raw_sql = preg_replace($keys, $values, $raw_sql, 1, $count);
  return $raw_sql;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use variable directly in the statement like following

```
$name="ABC";
$mail="me@someone.com";
$value= "I am $name mail id $mail";
```