# MYSQL Error Get Prepared Statement

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement

How do I get the prepared statement of the mysqli_stmt-object?

If there is an error while executing the mysql-statement I want to return the statement.

```
$id = "89c483c8";
$query = "SELECT * FROM database WHERE id = ?";
if (!($stmt = $database->prepare($query) { ... }
else {
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $id);
    if (!$stmt->execute())
         return $stmt->get_statement; //doesn't exist
}
```

"$stmt->get_statement" of course doesn't work. So how do I get the full query? In this example:

```
"SELECT * FROM database WHERE id = 89c483c8"
```

Comment: You should quote the hex value.

Comment: There's no such opportunity. Just use `error` property. Similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2691707/is-there-any-way-to-print-the-actual-query-that-mysqli-execute-makes

Answer (score 2):

This is the best way to catch sql errors :

```
try {
    $res = $mysqli_instance->query($query);
}catch (mysqli_sql_exception $e) {
    print "Error Code <br>".$e->getCode();
    print "Error Message <br>".$e->getMessage();
    print "Strack Trace <br>".nl2br($e->getTraceAsString());
}
```

Or the simplest way :

```
echo $stmt->error
```

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php