# PHP: "... variables can be passed by reference" in str_replace()?

Tags: php, pass-by-reference, str-replace

I created a function to print a prepared-statement-sql-string with the variables in it, based on what I found in this other [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/962986/how-to-echo-a-mysqli-prepared-statement).

Here is my code:

```
foreach($params as $idx => $param) {
    if ($idx == 0) continue;
    $sql = str_replace('?', "'" . $param . "'", $sql, 1);
}
printError($sql);
```

When I run this I get: `Fatal error: Only variables can be passed by reference` for line 3. However when i use

`$sql = preg_replace('/\?/', "'" . $param . "'", $sql, 1);`

for line 3 it works fine.

Any idea why?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The very last parameter, count, is passed by reference. You can see this in the description at http://us.php.net/str_replace where there's a `&` in front of the variable.

This means you cannot use a literal `1` there. You'd have to do:

```
$sql = str_replace('?', "'" . $param . "'", $sql, $count);
echo $count;
```

You'll now have displayed on the screen how many instances were replaced.

Comment: Indeed, the OP has misunderstood what the `$count` parameter actually does. It's an "out" parameter, not an "in" parameter.

Comment: Quite right; changed my example to illustrate that and added an explanation.

Comment: Oh, I see. So there is no way to limit the amount of replacings taking place with str_replace()?

Comment: Nope. `str_replace()` does not have that option. As you've already noted, `preg_replace()` does.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the documentation for [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) and [`str_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) and you will see why.  `str_replace`'s fourth argument must be passed by reference, but this is not the case for `preg_replace`.

Comment: This is _also the case for `$count` with `preg_replace`_, but the `$count` parameter for `preg_replace` is fifth, not fourth. The OP was using `$limit` with `preg_replace`, which does something else.

Answer (score 0):

I rewrite from **VoteyDisciple**

```
$sqlLogin = "SELECT * FROM users inner join role on users.roleId = role.id WHERE email=?1 and password=?2";
function makeSql() {
    $args = func_get_args();
    if(isset($args[1])) {
        $len = sizeof($args);
        //var_dump($args);
        $sql = $args[0];
        for ($index = 1; $index < $len; $index++) {
            $sql = str_replace('?'.strval($index), "'" . $args[$index] . "'", $sql);
        }
        return $sql;
    }
    return $args[0];
}
$sql = makeSql($sqlLogin, $myusername1, $mypassword);
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
```