# Get query back from MYSQLi prepared statement

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement

My prepared statement looks like this:

```
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
echo "Connected successfully";

// prepare and bind
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO `devices` (`deviceName`, `type`, `deviceToken`) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param("sss", $deviceName, $deviceToken, $type);
$stmt->execute();
echo "executed";
$result = $stmt->get_result();
$conn->close();
```

And I want to echo the query.
I know the PDO method:

```
$binded_query = $stmt->queryString
```

But I need to use MYSQLi. 
So how can I do that?

Comment: What does the output look like if you do a print_r($result); ?

Comment: @Brogan Nothing. It prints nothing at all.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/962986/how-to-echo-a-mysqli-prepared-statement

Comment: @AlanTan I did it once but I can't find that code anywhere...

Comment: Can you try this statement instead? "INSERT INTO devices (deviceName, type, deviceToken) VALUES ('?', '?', '?')"

Answer (score -2):

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `devices` (`deviceName`, `type`, `deviceToken`) VALUES (?, ?, ?)"
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
echo $sql; // here you go
```

Comment: But, in this way, you can't see binded values

Comment: The Original Poster didn't ask that. But if you need values you can output them as well: var_dump($deviceName, $deviceToken, $type)